# Cakephp 2.5.4 Error after adding DebugKit

Tags: php, cakephp, web, youtube

As I followed the step by step given from [this Youtube videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bke5Vv0RcOg&list=PLy6f6YeaisJLnQpKpeeJX_ooJg_IH1Oib&index=5).

I'm very interested to know more about cakePhp.
But unfortunately after I followed adding the DebugKit as Step 04 from the videos.

I got the following error message:

```
Notice (8): Trying to get property of non-object [APP\Plugin\DebugKit\Lib\Panel\HistoryPanel.php, line 48]
Notice (8): Trying to get property of non-object [APP\Plugin\DebugKit\Lib\Panel\SessionPanel.php, line 29]
Notice (8): Trying to get property of non-object [APP\Plugin\DebugKit\Lib\Panel\HistoryPanel.php, line 48]
Notice (8): Trying to get property of non-object [APP\Plugin\DebugKit\Lib\Panel\SessionPanel.php, line 29]
Fatal error: Call to a member function read() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\fgroup\cakephp\app\Plugin\DebugKit\Lib\Panel\SessionPanel.php on line 29
```

What should I do then to make it working perfectly?

Comment: Which video specifically?

Comment: 4th Video .... @mcgowan.b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow [these](https://github.com/cakephp/debug_kit) instructions, and make sure the version of DebugKit is compatible with the version of Cake you are using

Comment: which version of the debugkit that used in the videos shown anyway?